# How to reset a form in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I need to reset a popup form where the values are all filled from session variables:

```
Template.customerinfo.name = -> Session.get('activeCustomer').name
```

Right now I'm doing it manually:

```
Template.customerinfo.events
  'click #cancelButton': ->
    Client.getById('inputName').val(Session.get('activeCustomer').name)
```

`Meteor.render` would be even messier because I would have to pluck the current form/template, create a new one with Meteor.render and then insert it into the DOM.

Is there a way to tell meteor to reset a form or template and pull the values from their sources?

Comment: Side note: don't use `Meteor.render`. This API will disapear in a few weeks when the new Meteor UI system will be released.

Answer (score 5):

In your Handlebars template, i.e. after you do a Meteor.call() or collection insert / update, put this jQuery call. It returns the 1st form in the DOM, then calls the DOM reset().

```
$('.add-post-form')[0].reset();
```

In your HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal add-post-form" role="form">
   // Your form HTML.
</form>
```

Also, see:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp

Answer (score 3):

just use `event.target.name.value = "";`

Answer (score 1):

Just have a condition in which the template (or variable) will render, and then change that condition. For example in the HTML have:

```
    <Template name="customerinfo">
    {{#if somevariable}}
      {{name}}
    {{/if}}
    </template>
```

And in the JS, have...

```
    var somevariable = true;
```

and these helpers:

```
    Template.customerinfo.name = function(){
       return Session.get('activeCustomer').name;
    }

    Template.customerinfo.somevariable = function(){
       return somevariable
    }
```

Since the template will get rendered only when somevariable is true, when you need to re-render the form, execute the function resetForm():

```
    resetForm = function(){
       somevariable = false;
       somevariable = true;
    }
```

Comment: it's not in coffeescript, but there's always js2coffee.org =)

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried with somevariable as a plain js variable and also a session variable.

Comment: if you use: || Template.customerinfo.name = function(){return Session.get('activeCustomer').name;} ||, what happens when you do || Session.set('activeCustomer', 'aDifferentName') ||? Does that cause a template refresh? Theoretically it should because [it creates a reactive context](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/97SEWb7Tfuc)

Answer (score 0):

i think you can add a hide reset button to reset your form.

css

```
.hide { display: none; }
```

handlebars tmpl

```
<template name="btn-reset-hide">

    <input type="reset" class="btn-reset-hide">

</template>

{{> btn-reset-hide}}
```

js

```
resetForm = (tmpl) ->
    if tmpl?
        ($ tmpl.find '.btn-reset-hide').trigger 'click'
    else
        ($ '.btn-reset-hide').trigger 'click'
```

call resetForm()